# Dynamic Javascipt array manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dynamic

let say I have example input data,

```
data = [
  { name : 'Alice', age : 21},
  { name : 'Henry', age : 20 },
  { name : 'Max', age : 20 },
  { name : 'Jane', age : 21}
]
```

and I somehow want to merge them and turn this data into following form,

```
result = [
  { age : 20, name : ['Henry', 'Max'] },
  { age : 21, name : ['Alice', 'Jane'] } 
]
```

I do not want to solve this with specific name of key or value. I want to handle dynamically. Thank you!

Comment: Did you attempt anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example that shows the type of iteration/mapping/manipulation you can use to turn arbitrary data sets into a grouping as you propose:

https://jsfiddle.net/6b2rp4n7/

```
const data = [
  { name : 'Alice', age : 21},
  { name : 'Henry', age : 20 },
  { name : 'Max', age : 20 },
  { name : 'Jane', age : 21}
];

const mapping = new Map();

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const element = data[i];
  for (const prop in element) {
    const key = prop + "" + element[prop];
    if (mapping.get(key) != null && mapping.get(key).val === element[prop]) {
        const matches = mapping.get(key);
      matches.list.push(element);
    } else {
        const matches = {val: element[prop], key: prop, list: [element]};
      mapping.set(key, matches);
    }
  }
}

let result = [];
mapping.forEach((val, key) => {
    if (val.list.length > 1) {
    let res = { matches: val.list };
    res[val.key] = val.val;
    result.push(res);
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
0:
age: 21
matches: Array(2)
0: {name: "Alice", age: 21}
1: {name: "Jane", age: 21}
1:
age: 20
matches: Array(2)
0: {name: "Henry", age: 20}
1: {name: "Max", age: 20}
```

I decided to exclude all groupings of a single element, though those could be valid as well.  I also left the value manipulation to you - there should be enough to go on here to build up the data structure you desire.  It is difficult to help much more beyond this without additional context on what you are trying to achieve and why.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can try my code:

```
let data = [
  { name : 'Alice', age : 21},
  { name : 'Henry', age : 20 },
  { name : 'Max', age : 20 },
  { name : 'Jane', age : 21}
]
let r = []
data.map(d => {
  b = r.find(a => a.age === d.age )
  if (b) b.name.push(d.name)
  else r.push({age: d.age, name: [d.name]})
})

console.log(r)
```

Comment: Your answer terribly lacks explanations and educational references (documentation) to the methods used. You should think about editing it. I upvote anyway because it is a lot better than the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Lets get our hand dirty on the trick. This is road map not a straight off solution but once you get the road map you will you can narrow it down to a function as per your own need.

```
    data = [
  { name : 'Alice', age : 21},
  { name : 'Henry', age : 20 },
  { name : 'Max', age : 20 },
  { name : 'Jane', age : 21}
]
```

now we need to search and reduce it to given set of unique age values through loops
we declare set of variables to play with

```
var a = [];
var c= [];
var i;
var ii;
```

var iii;
var iv;
Now lets loop through whole razzmatazz;

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  a.push(data[i].age)
 
}
 a=[...new Set(a)];
```

This gives us unique values of age as an array from data array. Problem one sorted. Now we create placeholder array from newly generated unique array

```
for (ii = 0; ii < a.length; ii++) {

  c.push({'age':a[ii], 'name':[]})
}
```

Now that we have placeholders set as per unique array we just search and match from
data array and populate name array in placeholder array.

```
for (iii = 0; iii < c.length; iii++) {
for (iv = 0; iv < data.length; iv++) {
if(data[iv].age == c[iii].age){c[iii].name.push(data[iv].name)}
}
}
```

simple as that really. you can go and make bunch of functions to make it clean but this is the simplest road map to tackle the issue.

```js
 data = [
          { name : 'Alice', age : 21},
          { name : 'Henry', age : 20 },
          { name : 'Max', age : 20 },
          { name : 'Jane', age : 21}
        ]

        var a = [];
        var c= [];


        var i;
        var ii;
var iii;
var iv;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

          a.push(data[i].age);

        }
          a=[...new Set(a)];
        for (ii = 0; ii < a.length; ii++) {

          c.push({'age':a[ii], 'name':[]});
        }


        for (iii = 0; iii < c.length; iii++) {
        for (iv = 0; iv < data.length; iv++) {
        if(data[iv].age == c[iii].age){c[iii].name.push(data[iv].name);}
        }
        }

        console.log(c);
```

Side note this is exactly the sort of day to day data manipulation issue I had faced so I incorporated functions into my JS framework which searches, compares  and populates arrays based on what ever value we have If i get time i would trow down the source here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [{
    name: 'Alice',
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: 'Henry',
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'Max',
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane',
    age: 21
  }
];


let data1 = data.map(({
  age
}) => age);

let data2 = data.filter(({
  age,
  name
}, index, arr) => {
  return !data1.includes(age, index + 1)
});

let obj = {};
let data4 = data.map((e) => {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(e.age)) {
    obj[e.age] = `${obj[e.age]},${e.name}`;
  } else {
    obj[e.age] = e.name;
  }
});
let final = data2.map((e) => {
  e.name = obj[e.age].split(',');
  return e
});
console.log(final);
```